# Amazon S3 Upload via iOS app w/ percent complete

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, amazon-s3, asihttprequest

I am uploading a file from an iOS app onto S3 that can get pretty large. (up to 3-5mb) I want to have a way to have a progress bar for the upload for the user to be able to see the progress of the upload. I have looked into multiple classes, but have not seen a solution.

The most popular online is ASIHTTPRequest, which supports asynchronous uploading, but I do not see where it provides a progress for me to display.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Now that ASIHTTPRequest is deprecated, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ASIHTTPRequest` provides the state information, but you provide the progress view. It's called [`UIProgressView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIProgressView_Class/Reference/Reference.html), and it's a subclass of `UIView`, which means you can drop it in anywhere there's already a view.

You hook up the request's delegate to your progress view — as data comes in, the delegate tells your progress view to update itself with the current progress of the request.

Read the "[Tracking Progress](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#tracking_progress)" section of the `ASIHTTPRequest` docs for more information.

Comment: Thank You! I knew how to use a progress view, but did not see the Tracking Progress section. This will make things much easier!